# Best way to call a javascript function like 'window.open()' in Smart Mobile Studio

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

I'm evaluating SMS and really enjoying the experience. I need to open a new window/tab on the browser using window.open(). I have got this working using an asm block but I can't help but feel that there is a better way which I don't know about. So, is there a more SMS way of doing the following?

```
  asm
    window.open('MyPDF.pdf');
  end;
```

Many thanks.
 Regards,
  Will.

Comment: This is a correct approach.

Comment: @gabr: You should add that-ish as an answer.  The question stands with 0 answers right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traditionally that was the only way, but in recent Smart releases you can also use the `BrowserAPI` entry point.

```
uses SmartCL.System;

BrowserAPI.Window.open('MyPDF.pdf');
```